# How to use a sql query and get data from one Excel sheet to another in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, oledbconnection, listobject

I have two excel workbooks. One has a list of target customers and the other has a a table of sales data. I would like to use vba and write a sql query to get the sales history for specific customers and move that sales history to a new ListObject in the Target Customers workbook. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried an OLEDB connection, but I can't seem to get it to work, and I'm even not sure that that is the best way to solve my problem.

This is an example of the code I currently have.

```
Public Sub GetSales()

Dim targetList As String

'Get list of target customers
Range("A2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
counter = Selection.Rows.Count

targetList = "'" & Range("A2").Value & "'"
For x = 2 To counter
    targetList = targetList + ",'" + CStr(Range("A" & CStr(3)).Value) + "'"
Next x


'Query I want to run
'SalesData is the ListObject in the the Sales Data workbook
sqlQuery = "Select * From SalesData WHERE Customer IN " & targetList


    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("SalesData").OLEDBConnection
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .Connection = Array(something in here??)
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .SavePassword = False
        .SourceConnectionFile = ""
        .ServerCredentialsMethod = xlCredentialsMethodIntegrated
        .AlwaysUseConnectionFile = False
    End With


'Return the queried sales data into a list object _
'on a new sheet in the Target Customers workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add().Name = "Sales History"
Worksheets("Sales History").Activate

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add '(results of query)
    .DisplayName = "SalesHistory"
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I thought I could attach my workbooks, I don't see a place to do that.

Comment: You will first need to set your connection and recordset objects, define your connection string to connect to that specific workbook.  In Excel Data Tab > From Other Sources >  From Microsoft Query > Excel Files.  Once you open that you can choose the workbook you want to treat as a database and once you have all the Tables and Rows selected you can click on the SQL button and it will give you your SQL string to place into VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a simple connection and query to another workbook.

```
Sub simple_Query()
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    dbpath = "your path here"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] "
    Set vNewWB = Workbooks.Add 'or .CopyFromRecordset rs to open workbook
    connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=" & dbpath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1""; Mode=Read;"
    cn.Open connstr
    Set rs = cn.Execute(CommandText:=strSQL)
    vNewWB.Sheets(1).Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    For intcolIndex = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Range("A1").Offset(O, intcolIndex).Value = rs.Fields(intcolIndex).Name
    Next
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent, nice code. There are two small typos "intcolindex". I found that if I had done any manipulation of the data before it was brought over, I had to save or else this code would bring over data prior to the manipulation.